# Moving file from one location to another in Mule

Tags: file, mule, mule-studio

I am new to Mule. I have to do the following task.

A file is at some location. I need to move that file to some other location. The criteria to select the location is based on file name.

Suppose, the file name is `'abc_loc1'`. Then this file is to be moved into folder **Location1**. If the file name is `'abc_loc2'`, it should be moved into **Location2**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Mule [file transport](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/File+Transport+Reference) with inbound and outbound endpoints to move files, and either set a dynamic path attribute for the outbound, or use [choice routing](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Choice+Flow+Control+Reference) based on the original filename. You will have the original file name available as #[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename].

UPDATE (example flow):

```
<file:connector name="File"/>
<flow name="exampleFlow">
    <file:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="File" path="/tmp/1" responseTimeout="10000" />
    <set-variable variableName="myPath" value="#[message.inboundProperties['originalFilename'].substring(message.inboundProperties['originalFilename'].indexOf('_')+1)]" />
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="/tmp/#[flowVars['myPath']]" responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="File" outputPattern="error#[message.inboundProperties['originalFilename']]"/>
</flow>
```

UPDATE 2:

to use choice routing replace the above file-outbound with something like this:

```
<choice>
    <when expression="#[flowVars['myPath'] == '1']">
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="/tmp/1" responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="File" outputPattern="error#[message.inboundProperties['originalFilename']]"/>
    </when>
    <when expression="#[flowVars['myPath'] == '2']">
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="/tmp/2" responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="File" outputPattern="error#[message.inboundProperties['originalFilename']]"/>
    </when>
</choice>
```

Comment: can you please share the configuration xml file

Comment: Added a simple example that roughly corresponds to your description.

Comment: Thanks Anton, actually my file name doesn't contain location it only gives hint which location the file should placed into.For eg, if file name is abc_loc1, loc1 is not the actual folder, it's just the identifier to the location.Like loc1 could tell me that folder location is '/tmp/data' etc

Comment: updated my post again with the choice routing option